# Create array from HTML unordered list

Tags: javascript, html

I have an unordered list, each element of which I want to put in an array.

```
<div id='main'>
 <ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I need to transfer it to JSON object like this:

```
"type": "list",
"data": ["* First", "* Second"]
```

For now, i have function which return all data from list in string:

```
let newObj = document.createElement("div");
newObj.innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('UL')[0].innerHTML;
[...newObj.querySelectorAll("li")].forEach(ele => ele.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode("* "+ele.textContent)),ele);
return newObj
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can select all of the `li`. Then map it getting textContent and adding `*` as prefix

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('#main li');
const result = {
  type: 'list',
  data: Array.from(items).map(el => `* ${el.textContent}`),
}
console.log(result)
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery:

```
let $li = $('#main').find('li') //returns a collection
let array = $.map($li, e => '* ' + e.textContent)
```

Converting to JSON:

```
let toJson = JSON.stringify(array)
```

Comment: OP does not mention jquery, and jquery does not bring any additional value over mark's answer